# Recursive sets vs constructible sets in ${\cal P}(\omega)$

Tags: set-theory, computability

Let $D$ be the set of all recursive (aka decidable) sets of
integers, and $C$ be the set of all constructible sets of integers
, i.e. $C=L\cap {\cal P}(\omega)$ where $L$ is Godel's constructible
universe. What inclusions hold or do not hold between $C$ and $D$ ?

My thoughts : $D$ is countable since there are only countably many
programs/algorithms to decide the sets. On the other hand, $C$ is uncountable inside $L$ because $L$ is a model of $ZFC$, and my guess is that $C$ should stay
uncountable inside $V$, so the inclusion $C \subseteq D$ should be false.

Comment: Everything you said is correct except one thing:  $C$ might be countable in $V.$  If ZF is consistent, then the theory ZFC + "the set of constructible reals is countable" is also consistent.  (You can find a model of this by forcing with finite partial functions from $\omega$ to $\aleph_1.)$  Even in a model where $C$ is countable, though, it's still true that $D$ is a proper subset of $C.$

Comment: @MitchellSpector Good catch. I skipped over that 'guess' since it was irrelevant to OP's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. $L$ contains all Turing machines of $V$ (since Turing machines are/can be coded as elements of $V_{\omega} = V_{\omega}^{L}$) and it evaluates Turing machines correctly. So $D = D^L$, where $D^L$ is the set of all subset of $\omega$ that are decidable from the point of view of $L$. On the other hand 
$$
C = \mathcal P(\omega) \cap L = \mathcal P(\omega)^L,
$$
i.e. $C$ is the powerset of $\omega$ as constructed in $L$. Since $\operatorname{ZFC}$ proves that there are non-recursive subsets of $\omega$, we have that 
$$
L \models D^L \subsetneq \mathcal P(\omega),
$$
i.e. $D = D^L \subsetneq C$.

We can be much more precise than that: Let 
$$
E = \{ I \in \omega \mid I = \langle M \rangle \text{ for some Turing machine } M \text{ that holds on empty input} \},
$$
where $\langle . \rangle$ is some primitive recursive coding. Then $E = E^L \in C$ and $E \not \in D$ (this is the *halting problem*). So $E$ is a canonical witness for $D \neq C$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1. Could you please remind me how we know that there are non-constructible subsets of $\omega$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy We can't prove that in $\operatorname{ZFC}$. It might be that $V = L$ is true and hence there are only constructible sets. However, if we add a Cohen real $c$ to our universe, then $c$ codes a non-constructible subset of $\omega$. Hence it is relative consistent that there are non-constructible subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: so (as I suspected) your statement that "ZFC proves that there are non-constructible subsets of $\omega$" should be corrected in your answer. Then I can accept it

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Whoops, I meant to say 'non-recursive'.

Answer (score 2):

Just an extra comment. Given that recursive sets can equivalently be described as $\Delta^0_1$-formulas, all these sets lie in $L_{\omega+2}$ (since $\omega\in L_{\omega+1}$). Given that $\mathcal P(\omega)^L$ is cofinal in $L_{\omega_1^L}$, there are many non-recursive subsets.

Comment: Why is ${\cal P}(\omega)$ cofinal in $L_{\omega_1}$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy One way to see this is that you can code any countable ordinal $\alpha$ as a subset $c_\alpha \subseteq \omega$. Now, if $c_\alpha \in J_\beta$ (the $J_\beta$-hierarchy is very similar to the $L_\beta$-hierarchy but with nicer properties at levels $\beta \neq \omega \beta$.), you can 'collapse' $c_\alpha$ to $\alpha$ and hence $\alpha \in J_\beta$. In other words: For every $\alpha < \omega_1$ there is some $c_\alpha \subseteq \omega$ such that $c_\alpha \in J_\beta$ implies $\alpha \in J_\beta$ and hence $\alpha < \beta$. By condensation we can pick $\beta < \omega_1$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy If one is a bit more careful, the same argument works for the $L_\beta$-hierarchy. Oh and by $\omega_1$ I (and Dan) mean $\omega_1^L$ - which is important to note.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Here's a simpler argument. By Lowenheim-Skolem applied in $L$, followed by Mostowski collapse, we get that for every $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ there is a $\beta$ with $\alpha<\beta<\omega_1^L$ and a transitive set $A$ of height $\beta$ with $L_\alpha\subseteq A$ and $A\models ZFC$ (we could get even more via condensation, but we don't need to). Now by Replacement in $A$, if $r$ is a real in $A$ coding a well-ordering, there would be an ordinal in $A$ of the same ordertype; so in particular, $A$ contains no real coding $\beta$. So any such real arrives after stage $\alpha$.